# While installing pgvector extension to PostgreSQL in Windows I am getting error with make command

Tags: python, postgresql, windows, langchain, pgvector

This is the error I am getting while using make command in windows command prompt

[image]

I am referring to [this page](https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector#windows)

Please provide any other ways to install pgvector in windoes

I tried by following pgvector source repository. I want it to be installed for storing Langchain Embeddings in the form of vectors

Comment: Please do copypaste the output into the question body, hyperlinked screenshot is unconvenient to read.

Comment: You ran ```make``` or ```nmake```?